# How do I turn "www.example.com/test.html" to "www.example.com/test" ? (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have wrote an .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test test.html [NC,L]
```

But I don't get why if I go (for example) to "example.com/testabc" it leads me to test.html anyway.
How do I turn this off?
I know it's a simple thing but I can't find the solutions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your expression:

> ```
> ^test
> ```

https://regex101.com/ will translate it into English:

> ^ asserts position at start of a line
>   test matches the characters test literally (case sensitive)

So you have a "starts with" but no "ends with"

```
^test$
```